# Agda Vec.filter gives a Vec≤, how do I go back to a Vec?

Tags: agda

I noticed that the signature for `Vec.filter` is

```
filter : ∀ {n} → Vec A n → Vec≤ A n
```

In order to go back to a `Vec` can I **only** use

```
padRight : ∀ {n} → A → Vec≤ A n → Vec A n
```

or

```
padLeft : ∀ {n} → A → Vec≤ A n → Vec A n
```

?

Ideally I would like to get back a `Vec` that has its length equal to the initial length of the `Vec` minus the number of elements that have been filtered out (instead of padding the spots where the elements have been filtered out).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the definition of `Vec≤`](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Vec.Bounded.Base.html#1153), you will see that it is already exactly what you are asking for:

```
record Vec≤ (A : Set a) (n : ℕ) : Set a where
  constructor _,_
  field {length} : ℕ
        vec      : Vec A length
        .bound   : length ≤ n
```

So `vec` of a `Vec≤ A n` is a "normal" `Vec A length`, for some `length` less than `n`.

Comment: Thanks! However, if I apply `filter` then I don't know what the length of the new `Vec` will be. I don't think the compiler will be happy with that. Does that mean I would need to stay in `Vec≤` or is there still a way to downcast back to a `Vec` having the new length?

Comment: for example: `DeleteNat : ∀ {n m} → (Vec ℕ n) → ℕ → (Vec ℕ m)
DeleteNat nats nat = Vec≤.vec (v.filter (λ e → e ≟ nat) nats)` gives the error `Vec≤.length (v.filter (λ e → e ≟ nat) nats) != m of type ℕ`